# writing a karma test funcantallity

Tags: karma-jasmine

```
vehiclelistServices.factory('VehicleListService', ['$http','$q', function($http,$q){
    return {
        getUserPrefs : function(url){
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http.defaults.cache = false;
            if (!$http.defaults.headers.get) {
                $http.defaults.headers.get = {};
            }
            // disable IE ajax request caching
            $http.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
            $http.get(url)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                d.resolve(data);
            });
            return d.promise;
        },
        saveUserPrefs : function(state,url){
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http.post(url, state)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        d.resolve(data);
                       });
            return d.promise;
        },
        getVehicleList : function(url){
            var d = $q.defer();
            $http.defaults.cache = false;
            if (!$http.defaults.headers.get) {
                $http.defaults.headers.get = {};
            }
            // disable IE ajax request caching
            $http.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';
            $http.get(url)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {              
                d.resolve(data);
            });
            return d.promise;        
        }
    };
}]);
```

can any one help me to write karma test funcantallity

Comment: It's too hard to read your code. please format it.

Comment: guys i just need  code snappet of only one function

Comment: lets say  saveUserPrefs  function

Comment: no body has replied